# How to disable debug in easyxdm library?

Tags: debugging, easyxdm

I need quick help , if anyone has knowledge about eaxyxdm then please share here how to disable debug in easyxdm?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use **easyXDM.min.js** instead of **easyXDM.debug.js** in your project. Just replace name of the file everywhere it's using.